# Aggregate sum without duplicated values of the same month, same reference but different date

Tags: r, aggregate

This is my df. As you can see it has unique values since the invoice could be claimed several times in the same month.

```
        Invoice        mtime            Client.Code. Invoice.Date   Amount
1      20170100000 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1006442   2017-01-23   645.75
6      20170100001 2017-05-04 11:57:06      1004791   2017-01-23   5798.10
15     20170100007 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1004775   2017-01-23   12912.81
21     20170100008 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1004775   2017-01-23   132.37
26     20170100011 2017-04-11 09:59:42      1004689   2017-01-23   13455.10
38     20170100011 2017-04-19 15:59:18      1004689   2017-01-23   13455.10
50     20170100011 2017-05-04 11:57:06      1004689   2017-01-23   13455.10
62     20170100012 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1004775   2017-01-23   15649.38
68     20170100013 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1004849   2017-01-23   6616.40
74     20170100013 2017-04-11 09:59:42      1004849   2017-01-23   6616.40
80     20170100024 2017-04-03 13:03:53      1004962   2017-01-24   3046.59
```

I would like to know the aggregate amount of the invoices claimed per month (mtime), so if the same invoice has been claimed twice in a month, just sum like one, but if it have been claimed in several months, it should sum one for each month.

I dont know how to do the trick.

Thank you.

Comment: See `?aggregate`. Give it a try and report back with any issues.

Comment: `Claimed.monthly<-aggregate(Amount~month(mtime),Claimed.basic,sum)`I tried but i dont know how to do exactly what i explain.

Comment: Are `Client.Code.` and `Invoice.Date` irrelevant for your goals?  What is the desired output?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data.frame is named `DF`, you can first create a variable that extracts the month and year from the invoice dates:

```
invoice.months <- format(as.Date(DF$Invoice.Date), "%m%Y")
```

Then create a unique identifier for each invoice claim, removing the replicate claims within each month:

```
unique.id <- unique(paste(DF$Invoice, invoice.months))
```

To get the number of unique invoice claims each month (from the earliest month to the latest month):

```
library(lubridate)
month.vector <- format(seq.Date(min(DF$mtime), max(DF$mtime), by="1 month"), "%m%Y")
num.claims.per.month <- sapply(month.vector, function (x) length(grep(x, unique.id)))
```

Comment: I get inspired by you answer and I did that (DF=Claimed.basic) `Claim.months1<-transform(Claimed.basic,new.col=format(as.Date(Claimed.basic$mtime),"%m%Y"))
                      Claim.months2<-unique(Claim.months1[,c(1,3:7)])
                       Claim.months3<-aggregate(Amount~new.col,Claim.months2,sum)`